# Difference in raster pixels between Windows x86 and Windows x64

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, gdal, shapefile, r

I have a huge problem and I can not find a reason for it. I have two PCa, one in my house and the other in my workplace. The first one is an old notebook with Windows x86 and the other is Windows x64. I work in R in geospacial topics, and I have huge difference between the two system. The idea of my work is get the pixels of a raster (NetCDF) inside of a boundary of my whateshed (vector), so the code that I used is something like this:

```
 ncin <- nc_open(ncfname) #open the ncdf file
 #extract the variable 'precipitation' and latitud and longitud     
 pp<-ncvar_get(ncin, varid = 'pr', start = c(1,1,1), count = c(-1,-1,1))
 lat <- ncin$dim$lat$vals   # latitude position
 lon <- ncin$dim$lon$vals  # longitude position
 # create a raster from ncin and transpose and flip the raster and extent 
 r <- raster(pp, crs ="+init=epsg:4326" )
 rt <- t(r)
 rt <- flip(rt,direction=2)
 extent(rt)<-extent(c(range(lon), range(lat)))
 #open the shapefile or boundary (watershed), the shapefile is in CRS:4326
 myShape<-readOGR(dsn = myShapefileDir, layer = myShapefile)
 #crop the raster with the boundary
 crop = crop(x=rt,y = myShape, snap='in')
```

Then I have like the raster map is slipped in Windows x86 in comparison with Windows x64, you can look the difference in the next image (The left plot is created in Wx86 and the right in Wx64:

[image: explain]

I know that right image is from GRASS GIS, but happens the same in R or GRASS GIS.

The correct image is the right, but I cant get the same results in Windows x86.

The netcdf file can download here at the end (it is call 'CR2MET_v1.4.2_pr_day_1979_2016') :

http://www.cr2.cl/datos-productos-grillados/?cp_cr2met=3

The boundary or shapefile can download from here (google drive, it is call 'polygon'):

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1N0w-mCYkPPk_kayTKnbkMJ8f3jsS4PuB

Comment: you're absolutely sure the netcdf is in epsg:4326? As the R code does not transform it (only renames it), and if it is in something slightly different, it will plot differently.

Comment: Hello Sam, the netcdf does not specify the epsg, but is the standard for latitute and longitude, so i assume that. the metadata of netcdf doesnt say anything, how can i know the epsg code?

Comment: The netcdf said : CDI: Climate Data Interface version 1.9.0 (http://mpimet.mpg.de/cdi  and Conventions: CF-1.6

Comment: yes it will be EPSG:4326 then. That is standard WGS84 lat long. Without access to the netcdf and polygon, it's hard to help

Comment: i add the links in the OP!

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay. It is base plot that is getting you here. Everytime i change the base plot size (in pixels) and write the image, i get a different position for the polygon. Using something like levelplot keeps the spatial positions true

Comment: Hello Sam, thanks for your time, im not sure if is only the 'base plot' because i did some operational in the raster (intersect with the boundary layer and the obtain the mean values of all pixel inside the shapefile) and i get different results so i assume that it is something like reference coordinates or something with the memory on the PC (i dont know really).